# jQuery load() and how to know when dynamically added images have finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

With jQuery 3.3.1 `load()` I am adding content with a few HTML `img` tags inside and then I want to check the viewport for visible elements AFTER 
all the pictures have finished loading.

My problem is that I am unable to know when the dynamically added pictures have been fully loaded in my `<div id="#content">`.

This is my JS code for loading the new content:

```
// Replace the #content with content from a file containing a few `img` tags
$("#content").load("image-list.html", function() {
    console.log("Now my images have fully loaded???");
});
```

I have tried this:

```
// Show me which event is triggered after load()
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});

// Check if I can get when the images have fully loaded
$("img").on("load", function() {
    console.log("Load image event???");
});
```

I also have tried some black-magic with waiting X milliseconds and looping through all image tags but this is for sure NOT the way to go as it is obscure!

The result of the above is:

- I get the `Now my images have fully loaded` message immediately after I have loaded the file but it does not wait to show the message to after everything has been rendered
- I do not get the `console.log(event)` message at all
- I do not get any `Load image event` messages at all

I am debugging this by slowing down the speed with Chromes network option:

[image: Speed debugging with Google Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `Load image event???` log is not firing, because you are not late binding the event handler on the images, thus, the `on` function will not fire for images that were added dynamically to your html.

To late bind, you can modify that function the following way:

```
$(document).on('load', 'img', function() {
    console.log("Load image event???");
});
```

But if an image takes a long time to load, and you are trying to do something after all the new images were loaded which came from your `image-list.html`, I suggest something like the below approach:

Try putting the load listener, inside the callback function of the `load` method, like this:

```
$("#content").load("image-list.html", function() {
   var numberOfImages = jQuery("#content img").length;

   $("#content img").one('load', function() {
      numberOfImages--;
      if (numberOfImages == 0) {
           console.log("All the images have loaded");
      }
   });

   $("#content img").each(function() {
       if (jQuery(this)[0].complete) jQuery(this).trigger("load");
   }); 
});
```

You just have to be careful, as apparently, the `load` event will not fire, if the image you are loading was already cached, and loaded from the cache. There are workarounds for that too.

**EDIT:** The above code will take care for the situation where the images are loaded from cache also.

Comment: I have tried it out but it only works for one image - not them all. I need the event when ALL images are fully loaded as I then know the images height are correct (then I can trust the viewport). I tried `$("#content").on("load", "img", function() {` but that did not fire any messages.

Comment: you mean, the `A single image was loaded` from my second example, fires only once?

Comment: Yes. It should also work as so according to the jQuery documentation, "The handler is executed at most once per element per event type."

Comment: If you have multiple images, you will have multiple elements there. The `one` is there only to ensure that this runs only once, for each element (ie: image). I've modified the code, please try it out.

Comment: Worked perfectly :-)